# Drawing in QQuickFramebufferObject via texture taken from an Item. It fails unless I repaint/update constantly

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2, repaint

What my code does, in short:

- Create a simple `Rectangle` named `rect`, with `layer.enabled: true`.
- Pass `rect` to an instance of my `QQuickFramebufferObject` subclass called `itemSnapshotter`
- In `synchronize`, take a pointer to the texture provided by `rect`
- In `render`, draw a rectangle textured with the texture I took
- When `main.qml` finishes loading, call `itemSnapshotter.update();` for the first and only time.

The problem is that the QQFBO draws nothing, unless I uncomment the `update` call at the end of `render()`. **Any idea why?**

**My code:**

*main.cpp*:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQuickFramebufferObject>
#include <QOpenGLFramebufferObject>
#include <QSGTextureProvider>
#include <QObject>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QOpenGLBuffer>
#include <QQuickWindow>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
// propertyhelper.h is from http://syncor.blogspot.bg/2014/11/qt-auto-property.html
#include "propertyhelper.h"

class ItemSnapshotter : public QQuickFramebufferObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    AUTO_PROPERTY(QQuickItem*, sourceItem)

public:
    Renderer *createRenderer() const;
};

class ItemSnapshotterRenderer
    : public QObject
    , public QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer
    , protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ItemSnapshotterRenderer() {
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();
        initShader();
        createGeometry();
    }

    void createGeometry() {
        m_vertices << QVector2D(0, 0) << QVector2D(0, 1) << QVector2D(1, 1);
        m_vertices << QVector2D(0, 0) << QVector2D(1, 0) << QVector2D(1, 1);
    }

    void initShader() {
        m_shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceFile(
            QOpenGLShader::Vertex, ":/PassThrough.vert.glsl");
        m_shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceFile(
            QOpenGLShader::Fragment, ":/PassThrough.frag.glsl");
        m_shaderProgram.link();
        m_shaderProgram.bind();

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        m_shaderProgram.setUniformValue("uTex", 0);
    }

    void prepareShader() {
        m_shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("aPos");
        m_shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("aPos", m_vertices.constData());
        m_shaderProgram.bind();
    }

    void render() {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        prepareShader();
        m_tex->bind();
        glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_vertices.size());

        m_window->resetOpenGLState();
        //update();
    }

    void synchronize(QQuickFramebufferObject* qqfbo){
        auto parentItem = (ItemSnapshotter*)qqfbo;

        m_window = parentItem->window();
        copyTexture(*parentItem);
    }

    void copyTexture(const ItemSnapshotter &srcItem) {
        QQuickItem* sourceItem = srcItem.sourceItem();
        QSGTextureProvider* sourceTexProvider = sourceItem->textureProvider();
        m_tex = sourceTexProvider->texture();
        GLenum err;
        while ((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            qDebug("\tgl error: 0x%x", err, 0, 16);
        }
    }

    QOpenGLFramebufferObject *createFramebufferObject(const QSize &size) {
        QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat format;
        format.setAttachment(QOpenGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil); // TODO simpler format
        return new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(size, format);
    }

private:
    QOpenGLShaderProgram m_shaderProgram;
    QQuickWindow* m_window;
    QSGTexture* m_tex;
    QVector<QVector2D> m_vertices;
};

QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer *ItemSnapshotter::createRenderer() const {
    return new ItemSnapshotterRenderer();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    qmlRegisterType<ItemSnapshotter>("ItemSnapshotter", 1, 0, "ItemSnapshotter");
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

*main.qml*:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import ItemSnapshotter 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Row {
        Rectangle {
            layer.enabled: true
            id: rect
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: "red"
            border.color: "black"
        }

        ItemSnapshotter {
            id: itemSnapshotter
            sourceItem: rect
            width: sourceItem.width
            height: sourceItem.height
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        itemSnapshotter.update();
    }
}
```

*PassThrough.frag.glsl*:

```
varying highp vec2 vTexCoord;
uniform sampler2D uTex;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTex, vTexCoord);
}
```

*PassThrough.vert.glsl*:

```
attribute highp vec2 aPos;
varying highp vec2 vTexCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 0.0, 1.0);
    vTexCoord = aPos;
}
```

Comment: It's saving a pointer. It also may change. Other thing: the order between `synchronize()` and the similar callback of that `Rectangle` isn't clear. That are probably the reasons to have `QSGTextureProvider::textureChanged()`.

Comment: @Velkan: Yes, it's saving a pointer, edited the post to reflect that. Re: "It also may change." - what may also change? Re: "the order" - did you notice that I'm calling `update()` (which calls `synchronize`) in `onCompleted`? I'm not relying on just QML's initiative to call `update`. `textureChanged` looks like it may help me make a workaround though, thanks.

Comment: The texture of the rectangle may change (I think it may even disappear when it goes invisible). You call `update()` in `onCompleted` - that's in the GUI thread. But `synchronize()` is called in the render thread. So there is some kind of queue in-between, or maybe QuickItems are marked for update, so they are processed when there is a next sync between render and GUI threads comes.

Comment: @Velkan: Sure, the texture of the rectangle may change. That's no problem for me. As for the rest for your message, I won't comment because it's speculation and doesn't seem to lead to a solution (other than "use textureChanged", which I'm already working at)

Comment: It's not a speculation. It's stated clearly in the qt docs, and there are even fancy diagrams with these two threads, each in its own color.